# Getting a attempt to index local 'myMap' (a nil value)

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

I'm new to using `corona sdk.`

I am trying to add pins to map view put when I added in the code to do it I keep getting this error

> attempt to index local 'myMap'( a nil value)

I looked something up and someone had a similar problem and they just had to add local myMap to the top.  I tried that and it didn't work. I was hoping someone could help me find out what's wrong.

Thanks for your help =)

```
local widget = require( "widget" )
local myMap

local locationNumber = 1 -- a counter to display on location labels
local currentLocation, currentLatitude, currentLongitude

local background = display.newImage( "bkg_grass.png", true )
background.x = display.contentWidth / 2
background.y = display.contentHeight / 2

local shadow = display.newRect( 7, 7, 306, 226 )
shadow.anchorX = 0.0        -- TopLeft anchor
shadow.anchorY = 0.0        -- TopLeft anchor
shadow:setFillColor( 0, 0, 0, 120/255 )

local simulatorMessage = "Maps not supported in Corona Simulator.\n\nYou must build for iOS or Android to test MapView support."
local label = display.newText( simulatorMessage, 20, 70, shadow.contentWidth - 10, 0, native.systemFont, 14 )
label.anchorX = 0.0     -- TopLeft anchor
label.anchorY = 0.0     -- TopLeft anchor


local myMap = native.newMapView( 20, 20, display.contentWidth, display.actualContentHeight*.7 )

if myMap then
    myMap.mapType = "normal"
    myMap.x = display.contentWidth / 2
    myMap.y = 400
    myMap:setCenter( 37.331692, -122.030456 )
end

local function markerListener(event)
    print("type: ", event.type) -- event
    print("markerId: ", event.markerId) -- if of the marker that was touched
    print("lat: ", event.latitude) -- latitude of the marker
    print("long: ", event.longitude) -- longitude of the marker
end

local options = 
{ 
    title = "Displayed Title", 
    subtitle = "subtitle text", 
    listener = markerListener, 
    imageFile = 
    {
        filename = "someImage.png",
        baseDir = system.TemporaryDirectory
    }
}

local options1 = 
{ 
    title = "Displayed Title", 
    subtitle = "subtitle text", 
    listener = markerListener, 
    imageFile =  "someImage.png",
}

local result, errorMessage = myMap:addMarker( 37.331692, -122.030456, options )
if result then
    print("everything went well")
else
    print(errorMessage)
end

-- A function to handle the "mapAddress" event (also known as "reverse geocoding", ie: coordinates -> string).
local mapAddressHandler = function( event )
    if event.isError then
        -- Failed to receive location information.
        native.showAlert( "Error", event.errorMessage, { "OK" } )
    else
        -- Location information received. Display it.
        local locationText =
                "Latitude: " .. currentLatitude .. 
                ", Longitude: " .. currentLongitude ..
                ", Address: " .. ( event.streetDetail or "" ) ..
                " " .. ( event.street or "" ) ..
                ", " .. ( event.city or "" ) ..
                ", " .. ( event.region or "" ) ..
                ", " .. ( event.country or "" ) ..
                ", " .. ( event.postalCode or "" )
        native.showAlert( "You Are Here", locationText, { "OK" } )
    end
end

-- A function to handle the "mapLocation" event (also known as "forward geocoding", ie: string -> coordinates).
local mapLocationHandler = function( event )
    if event.isError then
        -- Location name not found.
        native.showAlert( "Error", event.errorMessage, { "OK" } )
    else
        -- Move map so this location is at the center
        -- (The final parameter toggles map animation, which may not be visible if moving a large distance)
        myMap:setCenter( event.latitude, event.longitude, true )

        -- Add a pin to the map at the new location
        markerTitle = "Location " .. locationNumber
        locationNumber = locationNumber + 1
        myMap:addMarker( event.latitude, event.longitude, { title=markerTitle, subtitle=inputField.text } )
    end
end
```

Comment: Please mark which line the error is on, none of the myMap lines jump out as problematic

Comment: StackOverflow is not a "post all your code" website and make us debug it.  Post code snippets so we can help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that either `local myMap = native.newMapView( 20, 20, display.contentWidth, display.actualContentHeight*.7 )` is returning nil or a function is setting `myMap` to nil along the way.

I notice that in two places you reference myMap without checking for nil first, unlike at the top of the function:

`local result, errorMessage = myMap:addMarker( 37.331692, -122.030456, options )`

`myMap:setCenter( event.latitude, event.longitude, true )`

It is likely blowing up in one of these two places. I would check to see if either `local myMap = native.newMapView( 20, 20, display.contentWidth, display.actualContentHeight*.7 )` is failing or if one of your functions is setting myMap to nil.